# integer division java returns a double? What is going on?

Tags: java

See screenshot:

[image]

What is going on there? i see that we're casting 23F to an int so in choice "II", we wind up doing 23/7 which should give us 3... at least so I thought. But why do we have 3.0? Why do we get a double?

Comment: Hint: what is the type of `z`?

Comment: That image is extremely hard to read.  Please take the time to copy and paste the text into your question as text.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the context:

```
float x = myFunc(23F);

int myFunc(float x) { ... }
```

The right hand side of the expression is an `int` and you have correctly deduced that its value is `3`.

When you assign an `int` value to a `float` variable, the integer will be converted to a `float`.

This is an example of a *primitive widening conversion*.  It can happen in various contexts when you are going from a "smaller" primitive numeric type to a "larger" primitive numeric type.  The `int` type is "smaller" than the `float` type.  In general:

> `byte` < `short` and `char` < `int` < `long` < `float` < `double`.

---

> Why do we get a double?

See above.  But it is a `float` not a `double`.

When you output a number in Java using `println`, a `float` and a `double` will look the same.  The `println` method won't output a `float` with an `F` suffix.  The `F` and `D` suffixes are only used in Java *source code*.

Answer (score -3):

Because the function that return the result is assigned to z, and the type of z is float.